# Where do i create my own function in wp-admin

Tags: functions, wp-admin

i want to create my own function in wp-admin same like do in wp-content->functions.php, but i don't know where is the function file in wp-admin folder.

anybody know where is the function file in wp-admin folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function file in "wp-admin" folder, you do not need to edit that folder.

Wordpress has Plugin api to do that,
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/

Create a plugin and write function in your plugin file.

Comment: Slightly off topic but are the only locations for custom functions (not directly attached to the theme files) functions.php or a plugin?